# Google Maps curl animation in MKMapView / Map Kit on iOS4

Tags: iphone, google-maps, animation, mapkit, mkmapview

Anyone know whether (and if so, how) we can create the half-turned page effect Google Maps on the iPad uses to show the options to change the Map type?..

See below image to see what I'm talkin' about..

[image: Half turned page]

Incidentally, any pretty good Map Kit tutorials you guys know of that are out there? (covering anything new brought on through iOS4) Support for Map Kit ain't much out there it seems...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a new UIModalTransitionStyle in iOS 4.0 called UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl

re: good mapkit tutorials, watch the WWDC map overlays video.

Comment: I watched Session 127 - Customizing Maps with Overlays, there is nothing in the talk or demos regarding this curl. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Hey Jason, this is a two part answer to a two part question. The WWDC part was to answer his 'any good mapkit tutorials out there?' question. I should have made that more clear. Google UIModalTransitionStyle for how to use modal transitions.